# window.addEventListener not working but window.onhashchange working?

Tags: javascript

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange",myFunction);
console.log(window.onhashchange); //This one prints NULL

window.onhashchange = myFunction;
console.log(window.onhashchange); // This one working fine.

function myFunction() {
    alert("The anchor part has changed!");
}
```

Why I am not able to attach event listener using the `addEventListener` method ? But `window.onhashchange` working fine

**EDIT** I am indeed using the 'hashchange' not 'onhashchange' it was a typo.

Comment: The getter `window.onhashchange` is not set doesn't mean it is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `onhashchange` event. There *is* a [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) event:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', myFunction, false);
```

Likewise, there is no `onclick` event, but there *is* a `click` event:

```
element.addEventListener('click', someFunction, false);
```

---

testing `on*` properties for bound events is not an appropriate way to verify that a callback is bound. For testing, you'll have to trigger the event in some manner and have a test within the callback:

```js
window.onhashchange = function () {
  console.log('onhashchange property works');
};

window.addEventListener('hashchange', function () {
  console.log('addEventListener method works');
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="#example">Click this to test</a>
```

Successfully bound callbacks will not be exposed via the property.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pfnbk5jL/1/ -- still it is not working. I removed the prefix "on"

Comment: @javanoob, your test is incorrect. Binding events via `addEventListener` will *never* reveal the bound event on the `on*` property. If you [test in the callback you'll see that the event fires correctly](https://jsfiddle.net/st3pvxyd/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and **hashchange** but function does not fired...

**OLD CODE**

```
const router = ()=>{//load new data}
window.addEventListener('hashchange',router())
```

**This is load new data but page not reload and just how old data, **it fixed when i change to** **

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
router()})
```

hope it will help thanks